# Made a "virus", need tips

Tags: java, swing, awt, ram, virus

First of all, it's not really a virus that is used to spy, or steal bank accounts. I don't even know if it's a virus at all. I only made it to troll friends/people I know, and practice my programming skills. I will show you the code, then I will try to explain it a bit;

```
package pracatice;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class practice extends JFrame 
{
    public static boolean bool = true;
    public static int x = 0;
    public static int y = 0;
    public static int num = 0;
    public static TimerClass tc = new TimerClass();
    public static Timer timer = new Timer(30, tc);
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public JButton btn = new JButton("press");

    public practice()
    {
        setSize(100,100);
        setTitle("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setPanel();
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    public void setPanel()
    {
        btn.addActionListener(new listener());
        panel.add(btn);

        add(panel);
    }

    public class listener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        num = 0;
        timer.start();
    }
}

    public static class TimerClass implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            do
            {

            num++;
            JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("PC afected by virus");
            JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "Virus");
            dialog.setModal(false);
            dialog.setLocation(x, y);
            dialog.show();
            updateCordinates();
            }while(bool == true);
        }
    }

    public static void updateCordinates()
    {
        if(x != 1100)
            x += 100;
        else if(x == 1100)
        {
            x = 0;
            y += 50;
        }
        if(y == 650)
           y =0;


    }
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        new practice();
     }
}
```

So, at first it obviously builds a window, 100 X 100 px big. It adds a button that says "press". When you press, it starts a new loop, every 30 milliseconds. 
every iteration of the loop, it puts in a new `JOPtionPane.showMessageBox(null,...)` in a slightly different location.

At first, when I just made it, I didn't know it would be unstoppable. I ran it, and had to restart my laptop. When I pressed ok, it would put in another box, in the exact same spot. When I tried to open task manager, it would automatically minimize it, and go back into the "virus" window. So, the laptop was unusable. I had to restart it, closing some of my dads tabs...

Here are a few things I would like to find out;

1) If I left this run over night, is it possible, that the laptop ran out or RAM, and if it did, what would happen?

2) Can I make it that, when I press a button on the keyboard, the whole thing just closes?

Like I said before, I was only trying to prank my friends, and the program happened to not be closable... any advice?

Comment: Sounds like your virus is working great

Comment: *"any advice?"*  - Don't do it.  If you screw up and do some real damage ... or cause someone else to do damage to themselves ... you could get into big trouble.  Stick to pranks where there is ZERO chance of someone getting burned.

Comment: @StephenC so, it can ran out of RAM???

Comment: If you locked up the machine, the victim might lose files / work.  If the victim panicked, they might do worse damage to their computer.  If the victim had a deadline, dealing with your prank could cause them to miss the deadline, lose marks, fail, etc.  Or you could end up wasting IT support staff's time. Technically, what you are doing is illegal ..... in the USA at least.  Or, it could be a code of conduct violation with your school / university.

Comment: The point is that pranks with computers can have serious unintended consequences.  The fact that you didn't *mean* those things to happen is not a real excuse.

Comment: @StephenC  ok lol. So I will remove the loop, and make it so that when the screen I filled, the timer stops... That way, if I end up doing this prank, it will Close the box, when u hit ok or X...

Comment: As shown in [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), your program is incorrectly synchronized; the result of running it cannot be predicted.

Comment: @Eddie many of us spend time writing programs that do useful things or solve interesting problems, maybe you should try that instead of writing "prank" programs, to practice your programming skills.

Comment: @Phrancis many of you graduated from college, and are professional programmers, where I am just a 14 year old teen, trying to learn, in a fun way... + the virus thing, is just a part of a program, that took hours to make...

Comment: On mac, shut down by `Command + Q`.

Comment: @ifly6 shut down the Mac? Or the application

Comment: `Command + Q` quits the current application.

Comment: @ifly6 do you know how to do that on a PC

Comment: You buy a Mac. `Alt + F4` could work though. I'm not familiar with Windows.

Comment: As someone who has developed software for a number of years, the people I see succeed play with the language. It is an important skill to develop to be able to see somtbing and to understand how the programmer did it.

Comment: @RobertBaron - Sure.  Fine.  But there are better (safer) ways to learn IT than by playing pranks on someone else.

Comment: @Stephen C - instead of saying don't do, don't do it, why don't you suggest something interesting that would be useful.  Oh I have a idea, let's suggest he learn SQL so he can write accounting reports for his future cfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the computer will eventually run out of RAM. When that happens, nothing disastrous should happen other than your program crashing.
2. Not very easily, because `JOptionPane` windows don't let keyboard events get to the rest of the program. You'd need to use your own type of window instead of `JOptionPane`. You could then use a `KeyListener` that does `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Lol this is the opposite of what the other guy said

Comment: I felt obligated to post an answer because he was completely wrong.

Comment: Ermm ... 1) is incorrect.  Or at least, it is not guaranteed correct in all cases.  First, you are likely to fill up **virtual** memory ... not RAM.  Second, before you fill up virtual memory, is it conceivable the system will be pushed into virtual memory thrashing.  (It depends on how big your application's heap is, and what other applications are running.) When that happens, the operating system could kill another process rather than your one.   OOOPS!

Comment: @tbodt - Read about thrashing and the Linux OOM killer.

Comment: @Eddie - If the "other guy" is supposed to me, then read my comments again.  I never said anything like that (until ~5 mins ago).  My original comments warn you that it is dangerous to play computer pranks in general ... not that your particular prank is dangerous.

Comment: @StephenC There was a deleted answer.

Comment: @StephenC I am aware of the OOM killer, but this is windows, not linux.